native vs token gas usage on identical chain state on Aptos
I couldn't find a solid answer to this question, can native and token transfers gas usage differ like its in ethereum, or do they use same gas on same chain state, theoretically all the time?
Through my experiments i noticed both require only 6 Octas for transfer, always.
My questions are,

Is gas usage of transfer for Aptos always 6 Octas as i noticed, or can it differ at any moment?
Can token and native transfers use different gas amount on same chain state, or do they use same theoretically?

